# how to fix discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

using python im tring to create a bot thta moves a user from one voice channel to another

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def asw(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    channels = 1062106353230950430
    await member.move_to(channel=channels)
```

Answer (score 1):

In [`discord.Member.move_to`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=move_to#discord.Member.move_to) the parameter channel
requires the channel Object not the id. You can get it using[`discord.Guild.get_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Guild.get_channel).

The code will be:

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def asw(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    channels = ctx.guild.get_channel(1062106353230950430)
    await member.move_to(channel=channels)
```